# How to dynamically highlight words in an image iOS

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, image-manipulation

I am currently working on an iOS application that is to be used as a museum display. Part of the display concerns a speech by Abraham Lincoln. My client would like me to display the text of the speech with certain words and phrases highlighted. When you click on the highlighted words a popup annotation should appear. **The tricky part is that they don't want to use digital text. They want to display the words of the speech in the form of an image taken from a facsimile of Lincoln's own handwriting.**

I have a good deal of experience in iOS development, and I think I am up to the task of responding to clicks on the highlighted words with a simple `touchesBegan` event handler to get the `CGPoint` of the touch. However, graphics are not my strong suit. I don't have a good idea of what to do about highlighting the words. I imagine I need to use some kind of filter or mask, but I have never done this in iOS before.

Any help is appreciated (and **I'm very generous with upvotes**). Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be building up the composite image anyway, how about putting the highlighted text as the image on buttons set on top of the background, with the rest of the text as part of the background image?

If there's no button text, just the image (of the word or phrase) then you're sorted.